# Webview JavaScript fontSize,color,backgroundColor is not work

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I'm loading html webside from url to webview... And I have Seekbar...
On change it should increase or decrease It's fontSize...But I could not succeed...
Moreover,textColor and background color also are not worked... In Addition to this,changing body text is worked...

What I done?

***Code that are not worked***

```
loadUrl("javascript:(document.body.style.backgroundColor ='red');"); 
loadUrl("javascript:(document.body.style.fontSize='20pt');");
loadUrl("javascript:(document.body.style.color ='yellow');");
```

***Code that is worked***

```
loadUrl("javascript:(document.body.innerHTML ='test');");
```

Above code changed whole webview after seekbar changed.

So,I understand loaded internet url to webview to load javascript is work, but style effects is not.I was thinking loaded url child elements override parent so did this

```
loadUrl("javascript:(var elements = document.getElementsByTagName(\"*\");" +
                        "for (var i=0; i < elements.length; i++) \n" +
                        "{    \n" +
                        "    elements[i].style.fontSize ='30rem';\n" +
                        "}" +
                        ");");
```

***that is not worked aswell***

What could be problem??

***Update***

After @tiny sunlight says test on desktop chrome , I was thinking, child elements override problem

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("*")
                        for (var i=0; i < elements.length; i++) 
                        {    
                            elements[i].style.fontSize ='20pt'
                        }
```

work on desktop chrome. but in android it have different syntax cause of string literal and not worked..

```
   webview.loadUrl("javascript:(var elements = document.getElementsByTagName(\"*\")\n" +
                        "                        for (var i=0; i < elements.length; i++) \n" +
                        "                        {    \n" +
                        "                            elements[i].style.fontSize ='20pt'\n" +
                        "                        });");
```

Comment: getSetting().enabejavascript(true)

Comment: plz read carefully i said loadUrl("javascript:(document.body.innerHTML ='test');"); is worked, so this mean i enabled javascript.....!!! getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

Comment: Are you sure your code work on chrome?

Comment: readed https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=752 and added webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()); no work

Comment: No . I mean u open the link in a  desktop chrome.

Comment: nope did not tested on chrome

Comment: Try to test on chrome

Comment: So much thanks for saying that...tested on desktop chrome and seem child elements override parent css(changed bacground color and some part changed)... I set body element...but there are child elements with different css...now need to set everyelement with javascript

Comment: I think it would be like this!

Comment: webview.getSettings().setTextSize() to change TextSize.
webview.setBackgroundColor(0) to change background.

Comment: thanks for effort but should be done with JS

Comment: Try to improve my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieve it by a trick.

It's easy to oom, You can try to improve it.

```
            String b = "javascript:alert(document.getElementsByTagName(\"*\")["+0+"].style.backgroundColor=\"yellow\");";
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(b);
            for(int i = 0;i<100;i++){
                sb.append("alert(document.getElementsByTagName(\"*\")["+i+"].style.backgroundColor=\"yellow\");");
            }
            a.loadUrl(sb.toString());
```